# Forcing techniques in Algebraic Topology: is this possible?

Tags: algebraic-topology, forcing

I'm seeing a course of Set Theory and Forcing, and I have seen this is a huge tool in many branches of Mathematics. So, I've been thinking how Forcing techniques could be applied to solve problems in Algebraic Topology (which is the branch I like the most). Unfortunately, my knowledges in Algebraic Topology are not as advanced as I want. But, is my intuition a nonsense? Is there some literatury  in this line? I appreciate all your ideas.

Thanks a lot.